# Left/Center/Right DIVs with Vertical Alignment

Tags: css, html, center, vertical-alignment

Trying to set up a outer DIV that is 114px high and 100% wide (page width). Inside that I want three DIVs left, center and right. The height of these inner 3 divs vary. I'd like all three inner DIVs to be centered top to bottom (vertically aligned).

I have gotten close floating left and right or left:0 and right:0 but stuck on the vertically centered part. Left and right DIVs contain images center text only. Having a hard time getting images to show on jsfiddle so I can't provide much of an example, sorry.

I have found examples with top and bottom alignment but no luck centered.

Thanks!

EDIT:

TyBlitz, you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks! However, on your container div height - inner div height you then need to divide by 2. For your example:

```
114-50=64 then divide by 2 = 32 for top.
```

Also needed to play around with text-align (left/center/right) Not thrilled making all inner DIVs 33% but it works. Seems like I should be able to have them scalable width and still position them correctly.
Here is my fiddle with example images imbedded: [My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rplace/T7vxE/6/)

Comment: If you like tyblitz' answer then accept as n answer or at least upvote.

Answer (score 2):

[Like so?](http://jsbin.com/iDorEHO/2/edit)

Simply float the 3 divs, give each of them a height, position them relatively (important!) and give them a `top: container.height - innerdiv.height;` E.g. container.height of 114 & innerdiv.height of 50 => 114-50 = 64=> `top: 64px;`

**EDIT:** Well if you don't want to make your divs all 33% , with some simple math you can approximately position your divs with the `float` and `margin` properties.

Like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7vxE/8/) of yours I updated.

The math behind it is:

1. `Container.length - combined innerdiv.length = unoccupied.length`
2. `margin-left: unoccupied.length / x (eg 50px /  5 =  margin of 20% = 10px)`

Comment: Tyblitz, that is close but I'd like the center DIV to always be centered and the Left/Right always far left and far right no matter the width. If I take off the 33% width for each (Right/Center/Left) DIV they end up all left aligned one after the other

Comment: @RichP Edited my answer, does it fit you better?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can solve your problem, although you'll have to create 3 wrapper divs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="leftDiv">
        <div class="leftInnerDiv">Left Div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightDiv">
        <div class="rightInnerDiv">Right Div</div>
    </div>
    <div class="centerDiv">
        <div class="centerInnerDiv">Center Div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer,
.leftDiv,
.rightDiv,
.centerDiv{
    height: 114px;
}

.leftDiv{
    float: left;
}
.rightDiv{
    float: right;
}
.centerDiv{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.leftDiv:before,
.rightDiv:before,
.centerDiv:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

.leftInnerDiv,
.rightInnerDiv,
.centerInnerDiv{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.leftInnerDiv{
    background-color: red;
}
.rightInnerDiv{
    background-color: green;
}
.centerInnerDiv{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/pv6yJ/1/

Please note though:

- The right div is declared before the middle div in the html.
- My solution (css vertical align) doesn't work on IE7 or lower.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this example to show how to vertically align the container and use column count (css3) which will automatically layout the 3 divs into 3 equal columns.

```
-moz-column-count: 1;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
```

and for non supporting browsers (IE) you can just set the width to 33% and float left.

http://codepen.io/tom-maton/pen/oqsEJ

Hope this helps